# Running python compiled as exe in Windows 10 run in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, windows-10, pyinstaller

So I made exe file of python script that autofills info on my site and disregard captcha on Windows 10.

Using pyinstaller auto-py-to-exe to be more precise.

I want to share this file with individual who uses Windows 7.

I know simply running or changing capability would not solve this issue.

Is there any way to solve/bypass this issue?

These are the modules I used for this program.

```
import time
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as SOUP
import lxml
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import urllib
import pymysql
import psycopg2
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import base64
import sys
```

Comment: Did you already try it? Did you consider the platform? x86 or x64? I am packaging with PyInstaller exe for WinXP use so their is no problem with PyInstaller itself

Comment: This computer is x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2485) on PyInstaller repo, PyInstaller seems not to include natively the drivers for Selenium.

The workaround seems to be to specify explicitly were are the drivers installed.

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/8qmh4g/path_errors_with_selenium_and_pyinstaller/) is a way to do it

Comment: You are probably right. But I decided to just use other old labtop as base of compiling. Seems like it did a trick.